# not getting user id from from Auth::instance->get_user()-id in Kohana

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I am using auth module of kohana. I did register and login and its working fine. But when i do `Auth::instance()->get_user()->id` i get `NULL`

While login i do it with `Auth::instance()->login($validator['email'], $validator['password'])` and then redirect user to home page.

But when in one of the controller i do `Auth::instance()->get_user()->id` i get `NULL`

What would be the cause. Is that i have to first set something???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Mistake**

In the `_login` function of `modules/auth/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php`

In that i was doing the following

```
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$user->where('email', ' = ', $email)
    ->and_where('password', ' = ', $password)
    ->find();

// TODO remember to be done
if ($user !== null) {
    $this->complete_login($user);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

In above i was checking $user is null or not but if the email and password not match the user instance will be created with `NULL` values for all the columns.

So now i am checking `$user->id !== NULL` and it is working fine.

Comment: Whats the reason of changing module methods? Login already works with id/username/email (https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php#L76).

Comment: we need to make some customization, so we have to change it

Answer (score 2):

Try `Auth::instance()->get_user()->pk()`.

`pk()` is for primary key.

Works in KO3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($user->loaded()) {
    $this->complete_login($user);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

See [ORM::__call()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/ORM#__call) if you want to know what happends (since ORM::loaded() does not exist)